# change function if/else statement javascript

Tags: javascript, broadsign, dooh

I'm trying to work with .js but I don't know everything jet. I want to work with if/else, so that if the .accidents change in number (from 002 to 003). That the .counter are is reset to 0. So .accidents (ongevallen dit jaar) starts with 0. and when there is a accident we change that to 1. And the .counter (days without accidents - dagen ongeval vrij) reset to 0.

The change of the accidents takes place via Broadsign Publish (.json).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL1mb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf9x8.png) (Broadsign Publish)

**.JS**

```
function padZeros(str, len) {
  return Array(len - String(str).length + 1).join("0") + str;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".counter").counterUp({
    delay: 10, //delay - The delay in milliseconds per number count up
    time: 500000, //time - The total duration of the count up animation
    //86400*1000 (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 = 86400000 seconds in a day)
    padLength: $(".counter").text().length,
  });
});

function accidents() {
  let accidents = 0;

  if (accidents > accidents++) {
    result = counter(0);
  }

  return result;
}
```

**.HTML**

```
    <div class="container countUp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <span id="countDays" class="counter" data-publish-id="countDays">366</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-offset-1">
                <div id="accidents" class="accidents" data-publish-id="accidents">003</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**.JSON**

```
{
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "fields": [
    {
      "id": "countDays",
      "label": "Dagen ongeval vrij",
      "default": "000",
      "mandatory": true,
      "maxLength": 3,
      "myCount": 0
    },
    {
      "id": "accidents",
      "label": "Ongevallen dit jaar",
      "default": "002",
      "mandatory": true,
      "maxLength": 3,
      "myCount": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `accidents` is a function. So... What is `if (accidents > accidents++)` supposed to do? o.O

Comment: `if (accidents > accidents++)` how would this ever be `true`? The *same* value **cannot** be larger than itself. If you meant to write `if (accidents > ++accidents)` then how would it ever be `false`? The opposite issue this time - a value **cannot** be larger than the same value incremented by `1`. The logic of what should happen here is unclear.

Comment: I'm trying to work with .js but I don't know everything jet. I want to work with if/else, so that if the .accidents change in number (from 002 to 003). That the .counter are is reset to 0.

So .accidents starts with 0. and when there is a accident we change that to 1. And the .counter (days without accidents) reset to 0

Comment: Then you will have to store the “previous” number of accidents somewhere, so that you can then compare it with the current one. But so far your function `accidents` does not even appear to get called anywhere. _“The change of the accidents takes place via Broadsign Publish (.json).”_ - and that does mean what, exactly? You need to show us what you are doing in that regard, otherwise we can not tell you what part of that process to hook into to call the function _after_ the value was changed to begin with.

Comment: The .json file is for changing the information in Broadsign Publish, see pichture on the right side.